# How can I use expressions as arguments to EXEC?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building some scripts and found an annoyance to be that I can't provide expressions as arguments to EXEC.

Here is an example I have run into. I want to setup various items using a consistent format that includes the database name. I can't simply concatenate the strings when passing an argument

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule
    @schedule_name = 'FullBackup_'+@DatabaseName,
    ...
```

instead I have to declare a variable just for the final string and pass that...

```
DECLARE @ScheduleName varchar(100)
SET @ScheduleName = 'FullBackup_'+@DatabaseName
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule
    @schedule_name = @ScheduleName,
    ...
```

I have built up a command string dynamically when necessary which could achieve this but would rather not to do that every time. Is this a limitation in t-sql or is there a way around it?

Comment: Did you mean `@schedule_name = @ScheduleName,`?

Comment: Relevant connect item https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/352110/t-sql-use-scalar-functions-as-stored-procedure-parameters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a limitation in T-SQL. There are several scenarios where you can't build up a string dynamically, but rather have to do so beforehand.

For example:

```
RAISERROR('String' + @variable,1,0);
EXEC dbo.procedure @param = 'String' + @variable;
```

There are other cases where it is valid, but usually just for assignment, not for passing or doing anything constructive with the result, e.g.

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(32) = 'String' + @variable;
```

T-SQL is just a quirky language with a lot of parsing peculiarities and odd rules. I think it's just the nature of a long-evolving language with different folks in charge of implementation at different times (made more obvious by their changing stance on adhering to things like the ANSI standard).

Comment: Though in the first case you can do `RAISERROR('String %s',1,0,@variable);`

Comment: @Martin sure, but not `RAISERROR('String %s', 1, 0, @var1 + @var2);` :-[)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just doing some maintenance scripts (not stored procedures) then you can do this type of thing using [SQLCMD Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx) ( Query > SQLCMD Mode ), eg

```
:setvar databaseName yourDbName

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_schedule @schedule_name = 'FullBackup_$(databaseName)'
```

Variables have a batch scope and can even pass through to other scripts called with the :r command.

Comment: doing both scripts and stored procedures but will take a look, thanks